# TextToSpeech stop() not working

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to stop [`TextToSpeech`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html), when back button pressed. But speech not stopping, even if I close my App. Only when I clear cache, speech stopping. How can I solve this? Please, help me to understand.

```
private boolean mShouldSpeak = true;
TextToSpeech tts;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                tts.setEngineByPackageName(enginePackageName);
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                tts.setPitch(0);
                tts.setSpeechRate(1);
               speak();
            }
        }
    });
}
 private void speak() {

    if (mShouldSpeak == true)
    {
        tts.speak("Автор: " +getResources().getString(R.string.catAuthor), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(getResources().getString(R.string.catName), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(getResources().getString(R.string.catDesc), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }

}
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null)
    {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
public void onBackPressed() {

    onDestroy();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: Add logging in `onDestroy` - does it get to `tts.stop()` or is the tts object already null?

Comment: No, not already null. There is TextToSpeech@5089 in debug.

Comment: Which TTS engine are you using in `setEngineByPackageName()` - have you tried another to make sure it's not an issue with the engine? Ideally, you really need to use the TTS API properly and fully, before you troubleshoot. If you don't it can cause issues. Add the correct bundle/map parameters, an utterance id and assign an `UtteranceProgressListener` so you can log the speech progress and see if it is attempted to be interrupted.

Comment: My gosh, I'm so stupid. You're absolutely right. 
I just started to learn Android and don't know very much. Not always examples, which are studying, give a comprehensive answer. You really helped, thanks a lot! <3

Comment: Glad you sorted it - we were all beginners once... Which one of my suggestions was the solution? I'll put it as an answer

Comment: It was a problem with the engine. Not quite knowing what it means setEngineByPackageName, I left the value from the example. Then changed to my package from the manifest. After your comment I tried to remove this option at all. And tts was to stop correctly. Thanks again, even though I do not fully understand the value setEngineByPackeageName, but I am ashamed of all this. And I will try to understand it)

Comment: Added an answer with a further link in regarding Text to Speech engine debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments, you need to ensure:

`tts.setEngineByPackageName(enginePackageName)`

contains a valid package name of a Text to Speech engine that is installed on the device, such as `com.google.android.tts` or `com.svox.pico`.

To check information regarding installed engines, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25723262/1256219)

Not applying this parameter will bind the engine selected as the device default in the Text to Speech Settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void onPause(){
  if(tts !=null){
     tts.stop();
     tts.shutdown();
  }
  super.onPause();
```

}

Stop speak on activity pause

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are creating numerous [`TextToSpeech`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) objects? Then it might be that you are stopping the wrong `tts`.

Try a simple

```
if (tts == null) {
    tts = new TextToSpeech(...) {...}
}
```

to only initialise the object if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Tnx for advice, but it's only one TextToSpeech object. When I stop the process "speech synthesizer Google" in cache, TTS stops. How can I stop this process programmatically?

Comment: Does your `tts.stop()` return a `TextToSpeech.ERROR` (-1) or a `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` (0)?

Comment: Hello, tts.stop() returned SUCCESS(0)

Answer (score 0):

Modify like so, this usually works for me: I believe that you are using multiple [`TextToSpeech`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) Objects, even if you do not think you are. It is a common problem.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        if(tts != null){
            tts.shutdown();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: I just... cant understand, sorry :c
Why this happening? How to solve this? Cause it's still not working. What I doing wrong?