# set Hindi as TextToSpeech language in android programmatically

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Unable to set hindi as speech language of texttospeech even though My mobile tts engine fully supports hindi textospeech

```
        if(t1.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("hi_IN"))==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            t1.setLanguage(new Locale ("hi_IN"));
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: t1 is texttospeech object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text to Speech Locale Hindi Indian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598587/text-to-speech-locale-hindi-indian)

Comment: i tried even  that code also but unable to set hindi language ,  could you post some more stuff or give sample code for that

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as a test, set your text to speech engine to Hindi in the Android Text to Speech Settings. Without having to apply any changes to your code, it should successfully speak in Hindi. If it doesn't, check the log output to see if there is a problem.

Next, your code is reliant on [isLanguageAvailable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable(java.util.Locale)) returning [TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#LANG_AVAILABLE), if it doesn't you will not attempt to set the Locale. There are many other possible responses. Check the log output of the two case switch statements below.

```
    final Locale loc = new Locale("hin", "IND");

    // switch(tts.isLanguageAvailable(loc)){
    switch(tts.setLanguage(loc)){

        case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE:
            Log.i("TAG", "LANG_AVAILABLE");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
            Log.i("TAG", "LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE:
            Log.i("TAG", "LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA:
            Log.i("TAG", "LANG_MISSING_DATA");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            Log.i("TAG", "LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED");
            break;
    }
```

Please be aware, the responses to `isLanguageAvailable()` are notoriously unreliable. See [my edit on the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21485614/1256219) as to why.

Finally, make sure you are setting the language of the TTS object after `onInit()` has returned `SUCCESS`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
t1.setLanguage( new Locale( "hin", "IND", "variant" ) );
```

I hope it will work if it was not till now.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

t1.setLanguage(new Locale ("hi","IN"));

instead of

t1.setLanguage(new Locale ("hi_IN"));

i hope it will work..

Answer (score 0):

After creating an object of `TextToSpeech` class, you need to configure it (or check it's available state/values) into `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`'s `onInit()` callback. You will get reliable information there about your `TextToSpeech` object.

```
private fun initTextToSpeech(){
    tts = TextToSpeech(this,this) // TextToSpeech(context,listener)
}

override fun onInit(status: Int) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onInit: status: $status")
    if(status!=TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)return

    val locale = Locale("hi","IN")

    val isLangCountryAvailable = tts.isLanguageAvailable(locale)
    Log.e(TAG, "onInit: isLangCountryAvailable: $isLangCountryAvailable")

    if(isLangCountryAvailable==TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
        val setLanguageResult = tts.setLanguage(locale)
        Log.e(TAG, "onInit: setLanguageResult: $setLanguageResult")
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "onInit: availableLanguages: ${tts.availableLanguages}")
    Log.e(TAG, "onInit: voice: ${tts.voice}")

    binding.btnSpeak.isEnabled = status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS
}
```

Logs I got for above `onInit` callback:

```
MainActivity: onInit: status: 0
MainActivity: onInit: isLangCountryAvailable: 1
MainActivity: onInit: setLanguageResult: 1
MainActivity: onInit: availableLanguages: [ko_KR, mr_IN, ru_RU, zh_TW, hu_HU, 
th_TH, ur_PK, nb_NO, da_DK, tr_TR, et_EE, bs, sw, pt_PT, vi_VN, en_US, sv_SE, 
ar, su_ID, bn_BD, gu_IN, kn_IN, el_GR, hi_IN, fi_FI, km_KH, bn_IN, fr_FR, 
uk_UA, en_AU, nl_NL, fr_CA, sr, pt_BR, ml_IN, si_LK, de_DE, ku, cs_CZ, pl_PL, 
sk_SK, fil_PH, it_IT, ne_NP, hr, en_NG, zh_CN, es_ES, cy, ta_IN, ja_JP, sq, 
yue_HK, en_IN, es_US, jv_ID, la, in_ID, te_IN, ro_RO, ca, en_GB]
MainActivity: onInit: voice: Voice[Name: hi-IN-language, locale: hi_IN, 
quality: 400, latency: 200, requiresNetwork: false, features: 
[networkTimeoutMs, legacySetLanguageVoice, networkRetriesCount]]
```